# Trying to compare an int to an array length

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am working on a recursive maze problem where I have three options:

- Move one step forward
- Move one step backward
- Jump a certain number of steps forward

Inside the array, 1s are occupied spaces and I cannot travel there. 0s are open spaces for me to travel. I think my code is almost complete, but when I am about to leave the array my code breaks. Here is part of the code. This shows my method, the recursion, my comments on what should be happening, and the values in the array.

```
System.out.println(solvable1DMaze(new int[] { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 }, 0, 2));

private static boolean solvable1DMaze(int maze[], int idx, int jump) {
        // Create variable for array length.
        int arraySize = maze.length;
        // If the index + 1 is empty then move to the empty slot.
        if ((maze[idx + 1]) != 1) {
            return solvable1DMaze(maze, idx + 1, jump);
        }

        // If the index - 1 is empty then back up one space.
        if (maze[idx] > 0 && (maze[idx - 1]) != 1) {
            return solvable1DMaze(maze, idx - 1, jump);
        }

        // If the index + jump is empty then jump the necessary spaces.
        if ((maze[idx + jump]) != 1 && maze[idx + jump] < arraySize) {
            return solvable1DMaze(maze, idx + jump, jump);
        }
        // If we leave the array, return true.
        if (maze[idx] > arraySize) {
            return true;
            // Otherwise, return false.
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the line where it currently crashes:

```
if ((maze[idx + jump]) != 1 && maze[idx + jump] < arraySize) {
```

I'm trying to figure out how to output true if the change will make the value of maze[idx] a greater value than the arraySize variable, and false if there are no other legal moves (such as when the array reads 1, 1 and a +1 or jump cannot land on a 0) to show that the array is inescapable.

These are other test arrays I was given to make sure my algorithm works:

- [0, 1, 0, 0, 1] with jump = 2                        returns true
- [0, 1, 1, 0, 1] with jump = 2                        returns false
- [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1] with jump = 2            returns false
- [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1] with jump = 3      returns true

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks", exactly? Your if statement doesn't check whether the result of `idx + jump` is less than `maze.length`.

Comment: Breaks as in crashes. The program stops working with the "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException". I told it to check if idx + jump is less than maze.length right here: ```if ((maze[idx + jump]) != 1 && maze[idx + jump] < arraySize) {``` Unless I need to take out the maze[] part and just go straight up ```(idx + jump) < arraySize```

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do to check that the array index is in bounds (at the upper end)

Comment: I think there could be an optimization here. There should be a lot of duplicate calls. You can use a Map to store the results of calls. Then check if the current call was already calculated (if it's in the map)

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out! There may be a more streamlined approach, but I found out through an hour of debugging the different examples that I had to split my if statements up because my || or | checks were only looking at the first instance and skipping the other check if the first one was false. The program had too many options to not have all of the checks, so I had to create multiple if statements and put them in a certain order.

```
private static boolean solvable1DMaze(int maze[], int idx, int jump) {

        // Create variable for array length.
        int arraySize = maze.length;

        // If the index + 1 is greater or equal to the arraySize then we can get out!
        if ((idx + 1) >= arraySize) {
            return true;
        }

        // If the index + 1 is empty then move to the empty slot.
        if ((maze[idx + 1]) != 1) {
            maze[idx] = 1; // Make the current place in the array 1 before we move to mark our spot.
            return solvable1DMaze(maze, idx + 1, jump);
        }

        // If the index + jump is greater or equal to the arraySize then we can get out!
        if ((idx + jump) >= arraySize) {
            return true;
        }

        // If the index + jump is empty then jump the necessary spaces.
        if ((maze[idx + jump]) != 1) {
            maze[idx] = 1; // Make the current place in the array 1 before we move to mark our spot.
            return solvable1DMaze(maze, idx + jump, jump);
        }

        if (idx > 0) {
            // If the index - 1 is empty then back up one space.
            if ((maze[idx - 1]) != 1) {
                maze[idx] = 1; // Make the current place in the array 1 before we move to mark our spot.
                return solvable1DMaze(maze, idx - 1, jump);
            }
            // Since we've already checked + 1, + jump, and - 1 to find no legal moves,
            // return false to show we are trapped within the array with no valid moves
            return false;
        }

        // If no valid moves can be triggered, return false.
        return false;
    }
```